# Scope of std::string when put in map

Tags: c++, string, scope, std

I'm new to C++'s scope and kinda confused about the lifetime of an `std::string` when it's inserted into an `std::map`.

For example:

```
void loadMap(std::map<string, int> &myMap)
{
    int num = rand();
    myMap[to_string(num) + "_xyz"] = num;
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::map<string, int> myMap;
    loadMap(myMap);

    //Is the entry I just added to the map in loadMap still safe in there?
    //i.e., is the key, which is an std::string, still around? 
    //Or its lifetime's ended?
}
```

I did some test and it *SEEMS* to be OK, but I'm not sure if it'll ALWAYS be the case. Maybe I was just lucky that the memory where the std::string was hadn't been touched.

Comment: The lifetime of a map's contents is the same as the lifetime of the map.

Comment: @Treycos I  understand that `loadMap` modified the map DIRECTLY because I passed by reference, BUT what if the string's lifetime has ended?

Comment: The answer is above

Comment: I suspect that you're worried that the map is storing some kind of references to objects, like in Java. It doesn't; it stores the objects themselves. (When you're programming C++, you can forget everything you know about references in Java. The word exists in C++, but it means a different thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following operation will create a `std::string` rvalue

```
to_string(num) + "_xyz"
```

Since the `Key` type for the `map` is `std::string` **by value** then this rvalue will effectively be moved into the map. In which case you are safe. The map now "owns" that string. Therefore the lifetime of the string is the same as that of the map in `main`

Comment: _"The following operation will create a std::string&& rvalue reference"_ No it won't. It'll create a `std::string` ([no references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)), and the expression will have rvalue category. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, the map is safe, all entries have valid values.

If you look at [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), you will see that the key either has to be:

- `CopyConstructible` in case that the key/value pair for that key doesn't exist (and/or the key cannot be moved)
- `MoveConstructible` in case where the key can be moved, without making any copies

This has a reason: the container will copy (or move) the key to store it. It will not store a pointer or reference if the key doesn't exist.

Same goes for the value: it is a reference to a value already stored in the map, and so when you do

```
myMap[to_string(num) + "_xyz"] = num;
```

you're copying `num` to to the internal value of the container.

Comment: A copy here is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right :) Thanks

Comment: Oh and `CopyConstructible` is wrong; you need to look at definition #2

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I guess it is only partly wrong. I'm going to change it.